# Top-bar goes missing in Safari

Tags: bug, top-bar, safari

Cocoa has support for tapping on links with three fingers; this brings up a popup with a WebView. Safari sets the behaviour so that the user can scroll through the website in this popup, but when it's clicked, a new tab opens with the website. Everything works as expected in this popup, but today, I noticed an error when it opens in a new tab; the top-bar on SO and MSO is missing.

[image]

[image]

I see that now, if selecting a different tab, and then going back to the tab with the missing top-bar, the top-bar is back in its position, but with a very low quality/resolution.

[image]